# Are requests for reference material completely prohibited?

Tags: discussion

Specifically, if I am looking for a very specific type of book, if one even exists, is that prohibited and if yes, why?

I ask because I would much rather ask the community for a good reference rather than reading through reader reviews on Amazon.com (which are not always valuable.)  Also, some books may not be excessively popular and it is more valuable to have a dialog or opinion of a person who is responding to what your specifically need.

Are these types of questions allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that because there is no one right answer, you'll get a lot of different opinions--and those types of questions aren't encouraged on ELU. Instead, I would suggest bringing up the topic in chat--you'll be able to engage in discussion for books that might help you.